# How can i close Half-Open (Dropped) TCP/IP Socket Connections

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, phpwebsocket

I have create a multiple clients socket connection.
Its working fine, but once if i remove the cable from one of the client it still shows a established connection. Is there any way to close the Half-Open (Dropped) TCP/IP Socket Connections in php.

Below is the code to create the multiple client connection socket server :

```
<?php

    /*! @class      SocketServer
        @author     Navarr Barnier
        @abstract   A Framework for creating a multi-client server using the PHP language.
     */
    class SocketServer
    {
        /*! @var        config
            @abstract   Array - an array of configuration information used by the server.
         */
        protected $config;

        /*! @var        hooks
            @abstract   Array - a dictionary of hooks and the callbacks attached to them.
         */
        protected $hooks;

        /*! @var        master_socket
            @abstract   resource - The master socket used by the server.
         */
        protected $master_socket;

        /*! @var        max_clients
            @abstract   unsigned int - The maximum number of clients allowed to connect.
         */
        public $max_clients = 1000;

        /*! @var        max_read
            @abstract   unsigned int - The maximum number of bytes to read from a socket at a single time.
         */
        public $max_read = 1460;

        /*! @var        clients
            @abstract   Array - an array of connected clients.
         */
        public $clients;

        /*! @function   __construct
            @abstract   Creates the socket and starts listening to it.
            @param      string  - IP Address to bind to, NULL for default.
            @param      int - Port to bind to
            @result     void
         */
        public function __construct($bind_ip,$port)
        {
            //sudo lsof -n -i :3490 | grep LISTEN
            set_time_limit(0);
            $this->hooks = array();

            $this->config["ip"] = $bind_ip;
            $this->config["port"] = $port;

            $this->master_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
            socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Issue Binding");
            socket_getsockname($this->master_socket,$bind_ip,$port);
            socket_listen($this->master_socket);
            SocketServer::debug("Listenting for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port}");
        }

        /*! @function   hook
            @abstract   Adds a function to be called whenever a certain action happens.  Can be extended in your implementation.
            @param      string  - Command
            @param      callback- Function to Call.
            @see        unhook
            @see        trigger_hooks
            @result     void
         */
        public function hook($command,$function)
        {
            $command = strtoupper($command);
            if(!isset($this->hooks[$command])) { $this->hooks[$command] = array(); }
            $k = array_search($function,$this->hooks[$command]);
            if($k === FALSE)
            {
                $this->hooks[$command][] = $function;
            }
        }

        /*! @function   unhook
            @abstract   Deletes a function from the call list for a certain action.  Can be extended in your implementation.
            @param      string  - Command
            @param      callback- Function to Delete from Call List
            @see        hook
            @see        trigger_hooks
            @result     void
         */
        public function unhook($command = NULL,$function)
        {
            $command = strtoupper($command);
            if($command !== NULL)
            {
                $k = array_search($function,$this->hooks[$command]);
                if($k !== FALSE)
                {
                    unset($this->hooks[$command][$k]);
                }
            } else {
                $k = array_search($this->user_funcs,$function);
                if($k !== FALSE)
                {
                    unset($this->user_funcs[$k]);
                }
            }
        }

        /*! @function   loop_once
            @abstract   Runs the class's actions once.
            @discussion Should only be used if you want to run additional checks during server operation.  Otherwise, use infinite_loop()
            @param      void
            @see        infinite_loop
            @result     bool    - True
        */
        public function loop_once()
        {
            // Setup Clients Listen Socket For Reading
            $read =array();
            $write = array();
            $except = array();
            $read[0] = $this->master_socket;
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
            {
                if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    $read[$i + 1] = $this->clients[$i]->socket;
                }
            }

            // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
            if(socket_select($read,$write, $except, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)
            {
                //SocketServer::debug("Problem blocking socket_select?");
                return true;
            }

            // Handle new Connections
            if(in_array($this->master_socket, $read))
            {
                for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
                {
                    if(empty($this->clients[$i]))
                    {
                        $temp_sock = $this->master_socket;
                        $this->clients[$i] = new SocketServerClient($this->master_socket,$i);
                        $this->trigger_hooks("CONNECT",$this->clients[$i],"");
                        break;
                    }
                    elseif($i == ($this->max_clients-1))
                    {
                        SocketServer::debug("Too many clients... :( ");
                    }
                }

            }

            // Handle Input
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++) // for each client
            {
                if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    //SocketServer::debug(implode('||',$read).' --> check 1 '.$this->clients[$i]->socket);
                    if(in_array($this->clients[$i]->socket, $read))
                    {
                        $input = socket_read($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                        SocketServer::debug($this->clients[$i]->socket.' -->    '.$input);

                        if($input == null || $input == 0 || $input == '')
                        {
                            $this->disconnect($i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //$this->socket_write_smart($this->clients[$i]->socket,$input,"");
                            //SocketServer::debug("{$i}@{$this->clients[$i]->ip} --> {$input}");
                            $this->writeDataIntoDB($input);
                            $this->trigger_hooks("INPUT",$this->clients[$i],$input);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        public function writeDataIntoDB($input)
        {
            $gateway = new GatewayWebservice();
            $gateway->storeSocketGatewayData($input);
            $gateway->checkData($input);
            /*$file = time();
            $fp = fopen('data/testdata.txt', 'a+');
            fwrite($fp, $input);
            fclose($fp);*/
        }
        /*! @function   disconnect
            @abstract   Disconnects a client from the server.
            @param      int - Index of the client to disconnect.
            @param      string  - Message to send to the hooks
            @result     void
        */
        public function disconnect($client_index,$message = "")
        {
            $i = $client_index;
            SocketServer::debug("Client {$i} from {$this->clients[$i]->ip} Disconnecting");
            $this->trigger_hooks("DISCONNECT",$this->clients[$i],$message);
            $this->clients[$i]->destroy();
            unset($this->clients[$i]);          
        }

        /*! @function   trigger_hooks
            @abstract   Triggers Hooks for a certain command.
            @param      string  - Command who's hooks you want to trigger.
            @param      object  - The client who activated this command.
            @param      string  - The input from the client, or a message to be sent to the hooks.
            @result     void
        */
        public function trigger_hooks($command,&$client,$input)
        {
            if(isset($this->hooks[$command]))
            {
                foreach($this->hooks[$command] as $function)
                {
                    SocketServer::debug("Triggering Hook '{$function}' for '{$command}'");
                    //$continue = call_user_func($function,&$this,&$client,$input);
                    $continue = call_user_func_array($function, array(&$this,&$client,$input));
                    if($continue === FALSE) { break; }
                }
            }
        }

        /*! @function   infinite_loop
            @abstract   Runs the server code until the server is shut down.
            @see        loop_once
            @param      void
            @result     void
        */
        public function infinite_loop()
        {
            $test = true;
            do
            {
                $test = $this->loop_once();
            }
            while($test);
        }

        /*! @function   debug
            @static
            @abstract   Outputs Text directly.
            @discussion Yeah, should probably make a way to turn this off.
            @param      string  - Text to Output
            @result     void
        */
        public static function debug($text)
        {
            echo("{$text}\r\n");
        }

        /*! @function   socket_write_smart
            @static
            @abstract   Writes data to the socket, including the length of the data, and ends it with a CRLF unless specified.
            @discussion It is perfectly valid for socket_write_smart to return zero which means no bytes have been written. Be sure to use the === operator to check for FALSE in case of an error. 
            @param      resource- Socket Instance
            @param      string  - Data to write to the socket.
            @param      string  - Data to end the line with.  Specify a "" if you don't want a line end sent.
            @result     mixed   - Returns the number of bytes successfully written to the socket or FALSE on failure. The error code can be retrieved with socket_last_error(). This code may be passed to socket_strerror() to get a textual explanation of the error.
        */
        public static function socket_write_smart(&$sock,$string,$crlf = "\r\n")
        {
            SocketServer::debug("<-- {$string}");
            if($crlf) { $string = "{$string}{$crlf}"; }
            return socket_write($sock,$string,strlen($string));
        }

        /*! @function   __get
            @abstract   Magic Method used for allowing the reading of protected variables.
            @discussion You never need to use this method, simply calling $server->variable works because of this method's existence.
            @param      string  - Variable to retrieve
            @result     mixed   - Returns the reference to the variable called.
        */
        function &__get($name)
        {
            return $this->{$name};
        }
    }

    /*! @class      SocketServerClient
        @author     Navarr Barnier
        @abstract   A Client Instance for use with SocketServer
     */
    class SocketServerClient
    {
        /*! @var        socket
            @abstract   resource - The client's socket resource, for sending and receiving data with.
         */
        protected $socket;

        /*! @var        ip
            @abstract   string - The client's IP address, as seen by the server.
         */
        protected $ip;

        /*! @var        hostname
            @abstract   string - The client's hostname, as seen by the server.
            @discussion This variable is only set after calling lookup_hostname, as hostname lookups can take up a decent amount of time.
            @see        lookup_hostname
         */
        protected $hostname;

        /*! @var        server_clients_index
            @abstract   int - The index of this client in the SocketServer's client array.
         */
        protected $server_clients_index;

        /*! @function   __construct
            @param      resource- The resource of the socket the client is connecting by, generally the master socket.
            @param      int - The Index in the Server's client array.
            @result     void
         */
        public function __construct(&$socket,$i)
        {
            $this->server_clients_index = $i;
            $this->socket = socket_accept($socket) or die("Failed to Accept");
            socket_getpeername($this->socket,$ip);
            SocketServer::debug("New Client ".$i." Connected -> IP:".$ip);
            $this->ip = $ip;
        }

        /*! @function   lookup_hostname
            @abstract   Searches for the user's hostname and stores the result to hostname.
            @see        hostname
            @param      void
            @result     string  - The hostname on success or the IP address on failure.
         */
        public function lookup_hostname()
        {
            $this->hostname = gethostbyaddr($this->ip);
            return $this->hostname;
        }

        /*! @function   destroy
            @abstract   Closes the socket.  Thats pretty much it.
            @param      void
            @result     void
         */
        public function destroy()
        {
            socket_close($this->socket);
        }

        function &__get($name)
        {
            return $this->{$name};
        }

        function __isset($name)
        {
            return isset($this->{$name});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to send a message or change the keep-alive messages to discover a disconnected cable. The TCP connection will be considered closed once a message is not acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

Made change for closing half established connection and its working fine and you need make some changes as i am on linux machine ubuntu 14.04

refereed this usrl : [enter link description here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html)

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
<?php

    /*! @class      SocketServer
        @author     Navarr Barnier
        @abstract   A Framework for creating a multi-client server using the PHP language.
     */
    class SocketServer
    {
        /*! @var        config
            @abstract   Array - an array of configuration information used by the server.
         */
        protected $config;

        /*! @var        hooks
            @abstract   Array - a dictionary of hooks and the callbacks attached to them.
         */
        protected $hooks;

        /*! @var        master_socket
            @abstract   resource - The master socket used by the server.
         */
        protected $master_socket;

        /*! @var        max_clients
            @abstract   unsigned int - The maximum number of clients allowed to connect.
         */
        public $max_clients = 1000;

        /*! @var        max_read
            @abstract   unsigned int - The maximum number of bytes to read from a socket at a single time.
         */
        public $max_read = 1460;

        /*! @var        clients
            @abstract   Array - an array of connected clients.
         */
        public $clients;

        /*! @function   __construct
            @abstract   Creates the socket and starts listening to it.
            @param      string  - IP Address to bind to, NULL for default.
            @param      int - Port to bind to
            @result     void
         */
        public function __construct($bind_ip,$port)
        {
            //sudo lsof -n -i :3490 | grep LISTEN
            set_time_limit(0);
            $this->hooks = array();

            $this->config["ip"] = $bind_ip;
            $this->config["port"] = $port;

            $this->master_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
            socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Issue Binding");
            socket_getsockname($this->master_socket,$bind_ip,$port);
            socket_listen($this->master_socket);
            SocketServer::debug("Listenting for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port}");
        }

        /*! @function   hook
            @abstract   Adds a function to be called whenever a certain action happens.  Can be extended in your implementation.
            @param      string  - Command
            @param      callback- Function to Call.
            @see        unhook
            @see        trigger_hooks
            @result     void
         */
        public function hook($command,$function)
        {
            $command = strtoupper($command);
            if(!isset($this->hooks[$command])) { $this->hooks[$command] = array(); }
            $k = array_search($function,$this->hooks[$command]);
            if($k === FALSE)
            {
                $this->hooks[$command][] = $function;
            }
        }

        /*! @function   unhook
            @abstract   Deletes a function from the call list for a certain action.  Can be extended in your implementation.
            @param      string  - Command
            @param      callback- Function to Delete from Call List
            @see        hook
            @see        trigger_hooks
            @result     void
         */
        public function unhook($command = NULL,$function)
        {
            $command = strtoupper($command);
            if($command !== NULL)
            {
                $k = array_search($function,$this->hooks[$command]);
                if($k !== FALSE)
                {
                    unset($this->hooks[$command][$k]);
                }
            } else {
                $k = array_search($this->user_funcs,$function);
                if($k !== FALSE)
                {
                    unset($this->user_funcs[$k]);
                }
            }
        }

        /*! @function   loop_once
            @abstract   Runs the class's actions once.
            @discussion Should only be used if you want to run additional checks during server operation.  Otherwise, use infinite_loop()
            @param      void
            @see        infinite_loop
            @result     bool    - True
        */
        public function loop_once()
        {
            // Setup Clients Listen Socket For Reading
            $read =array();
            $write = array();
            $except = array();
            $read[0] = $this->master_socket;
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
            {
                if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    $read[$i + 1] = $this->clients[$i]->socket;
                }
            }

            // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
            if(socket_select($read,$write, $except, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)
            {
                //SocketServer::debug("Problem blocking socket_select?");
                return true;
            }

            // Handle new Connections
            if(in_array($this->master_socket, $read))
            {
                for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
                {
                    if(empty($this->clients[$i]))
                    {
                        $temp_sock = $this->master_socket;
                        $this->clients[$i] = new SocketServerClient($this->master_socket,$i);
                        $this->trigger_hooks("CONNECT",$this->clients[$i],"");
                        break;
                    }
                    elseif($i == ($this->max_clients-1))
                    {
                        SocketServer::debug("Too many clients... :( ");
                    }
                }

            }

            // Handle Input
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++) // for each client
            {
                if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    //SocketServer::debug(implode('||',$read).' --> check 1 '.$this->clients[$i]->socket);
                    if(in_array($this->clients[$i]->socket, $read))
                    {
                        $input = socket_read($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                        SocketServer::debug($this->clients[$i]->socket.' -->    '.$input);

                        if($input == null || $input == 0 || $input == '')
                        {
                            $this->disconnect($i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //$this->socket_write_smart($this->clients[$i]->socket,$input,"");
                            //SocketServer::debug("{$i}@{$this->clients[$i]->ip} --> {$input}");
                            $this->writeDataIntoDB($input);
                            $this->trigger_hooks("INPUT",$this->clients[$i],$input);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        public function writeDataIntoDB($input)
        {
            $gateway = new GatewayWebservice();
            $gateway->storeSocketGatewayData($input);
            $gateway->checkData($input);
            /*$file = time();
            $fp = fopen('data/testdata.txt', 'a+');
            fwrite($fp, $input);
            fclose($fp);*/
        }
        /*! @function   disconnect
            @abstract   Disconnects a client from the server.
            @param      int - Index of the client to disconnect.
            @param      string  - Message to send to the hooks
            @result     void
        */
        public function disconnect($client_index,$message = "")
        {
            $i = $client_index;
            SocketServer::debug("Client {$i} from {$this->clients[$i]->ip} Disconnecting");
            $this->trigger_hooks("DISCONNECT",$this->clients[$i],$message);
            $this->clients[$i]->destroy();
            unset($this->clients[$i]);          
        }

        /*! @function   trigger_hooks
            @abstract   Triggers Hooks for a certain command.
            @param      string  - Command who's hooks you want to trigger.
            @param      object  - The client who activated this command.
            @param      string  - The input from the client, or a message to be sent to the hooks.
            @result     void
        */
        public function trigger_hooks($command,&$client,$input)
        {
            if(isset($this->hooks[$command]))
            {
                foreach($this->hooks[$command] as $function)
                {
                    SocketServer::debug("Triggering Hook '{$function}' for '{$command}'");
                    //$continue = call_user_func($function,&$this,&$client,$input);
                    $continue = call_user_func_array($function, array(&$this,&$client,$input));
                    if($continue === FALSE) { break; }
                }
            }
        }

        /*! @function   infinite_loop
            @abstract   Runs the server code until the server is shut down.
            @see        loop_once
            @param      void
            @result     void
        */
        public function infinite_loop()
        {
            $test = true;
            do
            {
                $test = $this->loop_once();
            }
            while($test);
        }

        /*! @function   debug
            @static
            @abstract   Outputs Text directly.
            @discussion Yeah, should probably make a way to turn this off.
            @param      string  - Text to Output
            @result     void
        */
        public static function debug($text)
        {
            echo("{$text}\r\n");
        }

        /*! @function   socket_write_smart
            @static
            @abstract   Writes data to the socket, including the length of the data, and ends it with a CRLF unless specified.
            @discussion It is perfectly valid for socket_write_smart to return zero which means no bytes have been written. Be sure to use the === operator to check for FALSE in case of an error. 
            @param      resource- Socket Instance
            @param      string  - Data to write to the socket.
            @param      string  - Data to end the line with.  Specify a "" if you don't want a line end sent.
            @result     mixed   - Returns the number of bytes successfully written to the socket or FALSE on failure. The error code can be retrieved with socket_last_error(). This code may be passed to socket_strerror() to get a textual explanation of the error.
        */
        public static function socket_write_smart(&$sock,$string,$crlf = "\r\n")
        {
            SocketServer::debug("<-- {$string}");
            if($crlf) { $string = "{$string}{$crlf}"; }
            return socket_write($sock,$string,strlen($string));
        }

        /*! @function   __get
            @abstract   Magic Method used for allowing the reading of protected variables.
            @discussion You never need to use this method, simply calling $server->variable works because of this method's existence.
            @param      string  - Variable to retrieve
            @result     mixed   - Returns the reference to the variable called.
        */
        function &__get($name)
        {
            return $this->{$name};
        }
    }

    /*! @class      SocketServerClient
        @author     Navarr Barnier
        @abstract   A Client Instance for use with SocketServer
     */
    class SocketServerClient
    {
        /*! @var        socket
            @abstract   resource - The client's socket resource, for sending and receiving data with.
         */
        protected $socket;

        /*! @var        ip
            @abstract   string - The client's IP address, as seen by the server.
         */
        protected $ip;

        /*! @var        hostname
            @abstract   string - The client's hostname, as seen by the server.
            @discussion This variable is only set after calling lookup_hostname, as hostname lookups can take up a decent amount of time.
            @see        lookup_hostname
         */
        protected $hostname;

        /*! @var        server_clients_index
            @abstract   int - The index of this client in the SocketServer's client array.
         */
        protected $server_clients_index;

        /*! @function   __construct
            @param      resource- The resource of the socket the client is connecting by, generally the master socket.
            @param      int - The Index in the Server's client array.
            @result     void
         */
        public function __construct(&$socket,$i)
        {
            $this->server_clients_index = $i;
            $this->socket = socket_accept($socket) or die("Failed to Accept");
            socket_getpeername($this->socket,$ip);
            SocketServer::debug("New Client ".$i." Connected -> IP:".$ip);
            $this->ip = $ip;
        }

        /*! @function   lookup_hostname
            @abstract   Searches for the user's hostname and stores the result to hostname.
            @see        hostname
            @param      void
            @result     string  - The hostname on success or the IP address on failure.
         */
        public function lookup_hostname()
        {
            $this->hostname = gethostbyaddr($this->ip);
            return $this->hostname;
        }

        /*! @function   destroy
            @abstract   Closes the socket.  Thats pretty much it.
            @param      void
            @result     void
         */
        public function destroy()
        {
            socket_close($this->socket);
        }

        function &__get($name)
        {
            return $this->{$name};
        }

        function __isset($name)
        {
            return isset($this->{$name});
        }
    }



    /*----------*/
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '127.0.0.1';

$port = 10000;

// create a streaming socket, of type TCP/IP
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);

socket_listen($sock);

// create a list of all the clients that will be connected to us..
// add the listening socket to this list
$clients = array($sock);

while (true)
{
    // create a copy, so $clients doesn't get modified by socket_select()
    $read = $clients;
    $write = null;
    $except = null;

    // get a list of all the clients that have data to be read from
    // if there are no clients with data, go to next iteration
    if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0) < 1)
        continue;

    // check if there is a client trying to connect
    if (in_array($sock, $read))
    {
        $clients[] = $newsock = socket_accept($sock);

        socket_write($newsock, "There are ".(count($clients) - 1)." client(s) connected to the server\n");

        socket_getpeername($newsock, $ip, $port);
        echo "New client connected: {$ip}\n";

        $key = array_search($sock, $read);
        unset($read[$key]);
    }

    // loop through all the clients that have data to read from
    foreach ($read as $read_sock)
    {
        // read until newline or 1024 bytes
        // socket_read while show errors when the client is disconnected, so silence the error messages
        $data = @socket_read($read_sock, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ);

        // check if the client is disconnected
        if ($data === false)
        {
            // remove client for $clients array
            $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
            unset($clients[$key]);
            echo "client disconnected.\n";
            continue;
        }

        $data = trim($data);

        if (!empty($data))
        {
            echo " send {$data}\n";

            // do sth..

            // send some message to listening socket
            socket_write($read_sock, $send_data);

            // send this to all the clients in the $clients array (except the first one, which is a listening socket)
            foreach ($clients as $send_sock)
            {
                if ($send_sock == $sock)
                    continue;

                socket_write($send_sock, $data);

            } // end of broadcast foreach
        }

    } // end of reading foreach
}

// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);
```